# UIViewControllerContext initalFrameForViewController & finalFrameForViewController show 0 for all values

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uimodaltransitionstyle

I'm implementing my own custom `UIViewController` transition and when I output to the debugger the frame of the TO View Controller, I receive `{{0, 0}, {0, 0}}` for both initial and final frame.  I thought that method on the context is supposed to show the expected frame after the transition for final, and the initial frame before the transition.

Is this how it is supposed to work?

```
-(void)startInteractiveTransition:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext{

    UIViewController *fromVC = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];
    UIViewController *toVC = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];

    CGRect initialToFrame = [transitionContext initialFrameForViewController:toVC];
    CGRect finalToFrame = [transitionContext finalFrameForViewController:toVC];
    NSLog(@"initialToFrame: %@, finalToFrame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(initialToFrame), NSStringFromCGRect(finalToFrame));
}
```

Debugger is showing:
`initialToFrame: {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}, finalToFrame: {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}`

Additionally, the Debugger is also showing the following warning. Does this contribute in anyway to the error?

`Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged`

Comment: Docs say that the methods can return `CGRectZero` when the view is not yet on the screen or the was completely cover during the transition. Maybe one of these is your case.

Comment: i have the same issue, and i don't have the debug message you are getting.

Comment: set `modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;`

Answer (score 1):

First thing you should know is that there are roughly two kinds of custom transitions: full and non-fullscreen and that asking for the final frame for `toVC.vew` in a non-fullscreen transition just doesn't make sense.

In the case where you don't set `modalPresentationStyle` or set it explicitly to `UIModalPresentationFullScreen` (this is the default value) UIKit know that `toVC.view` will cover the entire screen, so `-finalFrameForViewController:toVC` will return the correct frame: the main screen frame.

By using `modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCustom` you're specifying that the transition should be non-fullscreen, that's it: `toVC.view` will cover partially `fromVC.view` (and hence `fromCV.view` will be kept in the hierarchy), **where** `toVC.view` will cover `fromVC.view` is your decision, that's why `-finalFrameForViewController:` returns `CGRectZero`.

What that `CGRectZero` is telling you is: "Hey mate, leave alone, put that view wherever you want".

Check this presentations out for more information: http://es.slideshare.net/Split82/custom-uiviewcontroller-transitions

Hope this helps.

Comment: so , what about the initFrame ?